# Appending 10,000 tables using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, zonal-statistics

I am trying to append ~10,000 tables together using an ArcPy script.

I believe the method I am using does not work as the script is attempting to append too many tables at the same time. Would a possible work-around be a script that appends using looping?

```
import os
import sys
import string
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

WD = "C:/workspace"
arcpy.env.workspace = WD

#selects the 10,000 tables and tries to append them all together at the same time

arcpy.CreateTable_management(out_path=WD, out_name="append", template="C:/Workspace/template", config_keyword="")
tables1 = [table for table in arcpy.ListTables() if not table.startswith('append')]
arcpy.Append_management(inputs=tables1, target="ndvi_append", schema_type="TEST", field_mapping="", subtype="")
```

Comment: You may be better off just looping through all the tables and using an search cursor to read values and an insert cursor to add the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a code sample to implement crmackey's suggestion above. 1)Open an insert cursor for your final location, 2) loop each table, 3) check if table doesn't start with append, 4) read table data with a search cursor, consumed in a list, 5) use insert cursor to push table data into final table.

```
insertCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("ndvi_append", "*")
for table in arcpy.ListTables():
    if not table.startswith('append'):
        tableData = list(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, "*"))
        for data in tableData:
            insertCursor.insertRow(data)
```

Comment: The location of InsertCursor line seems incorrect!

Comment: Thanks @fatih_dur for your feedback. I updated my answer so that the insert cursor is only created once instead of every cycle of the loop.

Comment: thank you! code ran perfectly. also worked when the cursor was created every cycle of the loop

Comment: @user6665295, cursors are relatively expensive in terms of computational resources that you have. Obviously it is inserting a new row to the table whether you create once at the outset or numerous times with each loop, so practically working. But the current answer is logically correct. Also I suggest using `with` statement with **arcpy.da** cursors for a better efficacy.