# Appending 10,000 tables using ArcPy fails to complete

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I have been attempting to append 10,000 tables using the following arcpy code (from an answer to [Appending 10,000 tables using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211503/appending-10-000-tables-using-arcpy)):

```
WD = "C:/"  
arcpy.env.workspace = WD

for table in arcpy.ListTables():
    if not table.startswith('test_4'):
        tableData = list(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, "*"))
        cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("test_4", "*")
        for data in tableData:
        cursor.insertRow(data)
```

This code works perfectly for 5 or 500 tables. When I try to append 10,000 tables, the program runs for 5 minutes and then stops running. It does not give an error message, however. The program seems to still be running, although it is in fact not.

What could be causing this?

Comment: It appears as thought the script is crashing because the computer is running out of memory. Is there a work-around to minimize the amount of memory this program uses?

Comment: is this a standalone script? or within the pywin in arc?

Comment: No idea. Are you using 64 bit python? It is recommended you use the "with" syntax for cursors so that python deletes and does garbage collection for each iteration of cursor. Finally, try chunking your table list and using subprocess in your iteration. That will spawn a new process for each chunk of append statements. When the append finishes, the process will release the memory and hopefully keep it from crashing. It might be a bit slower but may actually complete.

Comment: What type of tables?  Geodatabase or DBF or something else?

Comment: Have you tried the `Append_management` tool, which will copy entire tables at once instead of copying things row by row?

Comment: The question is tagged ArcGIS-10.0, but your code features DA cursors, which weren't available until 10.1.  What version of AcGIS are you really using?

Comment: I am running ArcGIS 10.3. The script is being run in a standalone Python IDLE GUI. The tables are in a geodatabase. I tried using the "with" syntax, and ran into the same issue - the program quickly took up over 2 GBs of memory before crashing.

Comment: could you possibly elaborate on how to "chunk" the table list and then use subprocesses in the iteration? seems like my best bet at the moment

Comment: Append_management tool will not allow me to select the 10,000 tables without crashing ArcGIS.

Comment: Why convert the SearchCursor to a list? Try something like: `for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, "*")): cursor.insertRow(row)` Converting it to a list first is going to require the whole thing to be saved in memory. I believe the da cursors have something in place to allow you to iterate over larger features.

Comment: ^^agreed^^.  For chunking see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks. for subprocess see https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/

Comment: The issue seems to be coming from the line: [for table in arcpy.ListTables():]

Comment: the process of trying to list all the 10,000 tables seems to be crashing arcpy - any workaround to this?

Comment: @gis_user Please [edit] your question to make it clearer rather than adding numerous comments.  It is difficult to follow through the comments along with your question to understand the problem and what you've tried.